# Loggin into COUCHDB using curl

Tags: database, http, curl, terminal, couchdb

I would like to get the .json data from a specific http. The data I need for this is on a COUCHDB. Now when I curl http://example.com:port/mydatabase I get the message "You are not authorized to access this db. "I have now received header data with 1: roles, 2:username and a token. How do I enter my curl to get access to the database.

Tanks from Student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check is that you have created credentials for your database installation. You can read about that in the docs [here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/intro/security.html). Once that's in place, you can do basic auth with `curl` by passing your credentials as part of the URL:

```
curl 'https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@example.com:port/mydatabase/_all_docs'
```

More notes on how to use `curl` with couchdb are available [here](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.0/intro/curl.html).